# Can i colour black and white textures in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine

I've been trying to get into Eevee lately, but there's this huge problem im having. Which is textures. I've been using Blender Internal for the longest (i know, a rare gem i am) and there, you can just add a black and white texture, make it "multiply" and it instanly takes the colour of the material;
https://gyazo.com/d0e6d9e005dc812fc4709409d9eb788d (gif)
But in Eevee whenever i add a texture it just stays black and white:
https://gyazo.com/eb3fcffd4076653e45fce5854a0712ee

i havent found a way to fix this anywhere, do i really have to use an editing program and colour the textures in there or is there a way to do it on blender? thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Mix RGB node to multiply colors.

1. Add a *Mix RGB* node and set to *Multiply*
2. Connect your image texture
3. Use the other input for the base color

[image]

You can control the texture intensity with a *Color Ramp*.  And adjust contrast by moving the sliders.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This helped a ton! ^^ But could i ask one more thing? is there a way to make the texture have a slightly less effect on the material while keeping the colour of the materiald? like this; https://gyazo.com/fdb8959f755a4b26a0bac9847749877f (sorry if im not supposed to ask here)

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Cant thank you enough ^^

Comment: The MixRGB mode also has a "Color" mode, where the dark parts of colour slot 1 (if it's a mono texture) get replaced with the colour in color slot 2.